# Cannot login to fresh Kubuntu installation as admin, but only as guest

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login, kubuntu

I just installed a fresh Kubuntu 12.10 on a machine beside Windows 7. After successful installation, I rebooted and wanted to login. But when I type my password and hit Enter, some command line screen shows up for the split of a second and then it thows me back to the login screen without any error message. It's hard to spot what the command line text says, but I couldn't see any error or something like that. Anyway, when I log in as guest (without password), everything works finely. Also, when going to a system command line (using Ctrl+Alt+F1), I can login with my account without any problems.

Does anyone have a clue what is going on and how to fix it?

**Update:**

I made an image of the shortly appearing screen, there seems to be no special problem (sorry for the bad quality):
[image]

On the right side, every line says `[OK]`

Comment: Sounds like an XORG configuration problem in your specific user account.  Can you post the contents of ~/.xinitrc and ~/.bash_profile?  You can get them as root from /home/normalUserName/.{xinitrc,bash_profile}  (you may not have them, which might require you making them).

Comment: They did not exist, so I created them. I still couldn't login afterwards. What function do they have, why were they missing?

Comment: Btw, the shut down button on the login screen is not working either (it does absolutely nothing).
And: I managed to make a "screenshot" of the quickly appearing command line screen with my camera, see update on my post.

Comment: 1) Well they should have stuff telling your system what to do, the bash_profile is fine to not have but I thought KDE makes an .xinitrc...    Did it let you log in as root?  If so, can you get the contents of your /var/logs/xorg file?  If you cannot - see my next comment.

Comment: 2) If you cannot login GUI with Root:  hit Ctrl+Alt+F3, it should bring you to a text based login screen.  Type root and your root password.  Then try doing a full system upgrade.  _apt-get update && apt-get upgrade_

Comment: Ok, did this, and it installed ~5 MB of updates, but (in my opinion) nothing relevant for login. And still I cannot login, but the shutdown button on the login screen is working now! :)

Comment: Ok, I could start the GUI as root now by typing sudo startx and found the desktop environment of my old kubuntu installation (!), which I thought I had completely overwritten... So they must have been confusing each other, maybe I'll format the whole partition and re-install it. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: No worries, glad you figured a good path forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if others had a similar problem, this is what caused mine and how I resoved it:

I had installed a kubuntu 10.04 before (which was broken) and just installed 12.10 over it, assuming everything would be replaced. To my surprise, some fragments remained and interferred with my new installation. I could start the GUI as root by switching to a command line (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and typing `sudo startx`, just in case you need to backup some data. Then, I reinstalled Kubuntu 12.10 completely with the option enabled to format the selected hard disk partition before installing.